# Playing m7th chord on the 5th note of a major scale

Tags: chords, scales

Daniel Caeser & H.E.R.'s song "Best Part" has the following chord progression:

Dmaj7, Am7, Gmaj7, A#maj7

The song sounds like it is in D major, which means that the A chord should be Amaj or A7, but then why does the Am7 sound so amazing in this progression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are common and useful tricks. 
The way I'd explain the whole chord sequence is, it modulates between keys all the time:

1. Dmaj7 : establishes D major as the key
2. Am7 : gotcha! it wasn't D, it was G major!
3. Gmaj7 : yeah ... see, I told you, it was G major.
4. Bbmaj7 : oooops! the key is D *minor*! Fooled you twice!!
5. Dmaj7 : ha ha ha! the key is in fact D *major* ! You're so easy to fool! ;)
6. etc.

If we just look at the Am7, there are many ways to look at it.

- You can see the Am there just as a fancy D7, because it has the C note
  in it, the very thing that makes D7 push strongly towards G (using
  the "V-I motion" mechanism).
- Or you can look at it as "simulating" or "borrowing" or whatever, pretending for a short while that you're in the key of G major, where the Am - D7 - G would be a II - V - I movement.

Try replacing the Am7 with a D7. Then try replacing it with a D11 (i.e. C6/D) ... almost the same? No? What's different? Then take any song that has a D7 - G movement, and replace the D7 with Am7. Same? Different?

One of my favourite chord sequences is in Skee-Lo's "I Wish", based on a sample from Bernard Wright's "Spinnin'" (AFAIK). In "C" it would go like this: Cmaj9 - Abmaj9 - Bmaj9 - Gmaj9 (repeat). It modulates between keys in a very juicy way.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that the A chord *should* be A maj or A7? There is **nothing** anywhere saying it *should*. You've seemingly fallen into the trap that music theory prepares for all of us. It masquerades as the rules. Simply not true!!

One explanation - apart from the blindingly obvious one which you perceived - is that it belongs to the **parallel key**. That is, D minor instead of D major. That set of different chords can usually be borrowed from, as here.

Another is that Am7 has nearly the same note make-up as D9, which 9 times out of 8 moves directly onto a G of some sort. Here, Gmaj7.